# Get touchstart touches.layerX like mousedown layerX with rotated canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation, transform

I need help. I have rotated canvas with elCanvas.style.transform = 'rotate(25deg)'; I can get coords i desktop browser mousedown event.layerX and event.layerY. Via LayerX and LayerY i always can get click coords in rotated layer. I need to get rotated coordinates for mobile devices via touchstart. Its seems there no layerX. Need help. Has anyone encountered this problem? Sry for bad English.

Need help with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved )). Solution: remove all toutchstart and mousemove etc. use pointerdown, pointermove, pointerup events. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/pointerdown_event. Then use e.offsetX, e.offsetY instead of e.layerX. This works in desktop and mobile browsers + rotated canvas. Sry for bad English again.